# Change access form properties from a function

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to move the `OnClick` code from one of the buttons on a form to a function, but I'm having some issues. The button in question, called "Reset", changes the properties of most of the objects on the form. Stuff like:

```
Me.btnName.Caption = "Caption"
Me.btnName.Visible = True
Me.btnName.Top = 123
Me.btnName.Height = 456
'Etc
```

When moving this over to a function I can't seem to get this to work. I've tried a few different ways of writing it that I found while searching around, but none of them seem to work. I'm messing with some objects in the main form and some in the subform, so I'll show a few examples of both. Edited to include error messages

```
Forms("FormName").btnName.Caption = "Caption"
'Application-defined or Object-defined error

Forms("FormName").Controls("btnName").Caption = "Caption" 
'Ms Access cannot find the referanced form (I've double and triple checked that it is correct)

Forms("FormName").SubFormName.Form.btnName.Caption = "Caption" 
'Application-defined or Object-defined error

Forms!FormName!btnName.Caption = "Caption" 
'Cannot find the referenced form

Forms!FormName!SubFormName!btnName.Caption = "Caption" 
'Cannot find the field reffered to in your expression

Forms!FormName.Controls!btnName.Caption = "Caption" 
'Cannot find the referanced form

Forms!FormName!SubFormName!Form.btnName.Caption = "Caption" 
'MS Access can't find the field 'SubFormName'
```

No matter what I try of these I can't seem to get it to work. Maybe I'm just doing something simple wrong, or maybe you can't change properties like this from a function. Regardless, if anyone knows, I would appreciate the help.

Note that the function I'm trying to use is in a separate module, not in the code behind the form.

Comment: Is this function still in the form codebehind, or is it in a separate module?

Comment: Change `Me` to the actual name of the form: `FormName.btnName.Caption = "Caption"`.

Comment: Please explain *none of them seem to work* ... what specifically happens? Error? Undesired result? A few of those in lower code should work but you do not assign *Caption* to anything.

Comment: @fbueckert The function is in a serperate module.

Comment: @Parfait The errors are different depending on what I use. Some "Can't find the form specified", some "Can't find the object specified", the list goes on.

Comment: @KostasK. Using what you put causes the error "Object required"

Comment: That "reset" code **wants** to be in the form's code-behind, in some `Reset` procedure. Nobody outside the form should need to care about properties of controls on that form.

Comment: Roland - please relieve our frustration and the back/forth and edit your post to describe what the context (behind form, standalone module, etc.) of the attempted lines and the error for each specific attempted line. We can then help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a `OnClick` handler on some form's code-behind, responsible for assigning a bunch of properties *for objects that live on that form*.

What you have done is called *encapsulation*: outside code doesn't need to care about the `Top` and `Height` properties (and others) of the form's `btnName` button - truth is, outside code shouldn't even need to care that there's a button on the form.

So you're taking this nicely encapsulated object, and moving code around for no apparent reason.

If you need that functionality to be invoked from the outside, then yes, move it out of the `OnClick` handler.. but **not outside the form's code-behind**.

Move it to some `Public Sub OnReset()` procedure, and if outside code needs to invoke that logic, then have it call `theForm.OnReset`.

```
Private Sub ResetButton_Click()
    OnReset
End Sub

Public Sub OnReset()
    Me.btnName.Caption = "Caption"
    Me.btnName.Visible = True
    Me.btnName.Top = 123
    Me.btnName.Height = 456
    'Etc
End sub
```

That way you leave the implementation details of the form within the form itself, while giving outside code an *abstraction* to say "I don't care what your buttons are named; I don't care what size they are or what their captions are - but when I say 'Reset', you shall re-initialize whatever values you've got for them" - outside code doesn't need to know what `Reset` does *specifically*.

Put it this way: the day you rename that `btnName` button, would you rather need to simply adjust the form's code-behind, or hunt down every possible place in the entire project that could possibly be changing that button's `Caption` or whatever other property value?

FYI `Foo!Bar.Something` is late-bound code, shorthand for `Foo.Item("Bar").Something`: neither `Bar` nor `Something` are validated at compile-time. Contrast with `Me.btnName.Whatever`, where a typo is immediately picked up by the compiler: early-bound code that the compiler is able to validate should always be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property to something:

```
Forms!FormName!btnName.Caption = "New Caption"
```

or, if on a subform:

```
Forms!FormName!<NameOfSubformCONTROL>.Form!btnName.Caption = "New Caption"
```

Comment: Unless you assign the control value to a variable. :)

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but I am setting the properties to appropriate values.

Comment: Of course @Roland it is not clear because you do not show the value assignment in post.